# how to drawing a triangle on the surface of a 3D earth

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, drawing

I completed the 3D earth. Now I am trying to draw a triangle on the earth? but I failed to complete it, could you give me some cues or code to complete it? the following is drawing part in the sphere code. I could draw the triangle on the screen, but I do not know how to draw the triangle or point on the surface of 3D earth to render the latitude and longitude data on the earth.

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) 
{  
    float vertexArray[] = {
        SphereCoordinate(lat1, long1, 2).x,SphereCoordinate(lat1, long1, 2).y,SphereCoordinate(lat1, long1, 2).z,0.0f,
        SphereCoordinate(lat2, long2, 2).x,SphereCoordinate(lat2, long2, 2).y,SphereCoordinate(lat2, long2, 2).z,0.0f,
        SphereCoordinate(lat3, long3, 2).x,SphereCoordinate(lat3, long3, 2).y,SphereCoordinate(lat3, long3, 2).z,0.0f,
};
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); 
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);    
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);

    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, makeFloatBuffer(vertexArray));
    gl.glColor4f(.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // I want to draw the triangle on earth.
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);   
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, m_VertexData);          

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glClientActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);                                 
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture0);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, m_TextureData);         
    gl.glClientActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE1);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0,m_TextureData);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); 
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, m_NormalData);  
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, m_ColorData);    
    multiTextureBumpMap(gl, m_Texture0, m_Texture1);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (m_Slices+1)*2*(m_Stacks-1)+2);  
}
```

At the beginning, the SphereCoordinate(lat1, long1, 2(r)), the r is 1 which is equal with radius of sphere, but the triangle could not be viewed. Then I made the r be 2. And run, the final slot is the following image:

Actually, I want to draw the triangle on the surface of earth.

Comment: I could not add the shot image due to my reputation.

Comment: No one could solve it, you can send me email!